# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'reshape'

Tags: python, mnist

I'm following an article on medium called [Machine Learning: Improving Classification accuracy on MNIST using Data Augmentation](https://towardsdatascience.com/improving-accuracy-on-mnist-using-data-augmentation-b5c38eb5a903) and running into issues with the code in the article. The code is as follows:

> ```py
> from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
> from scipy.ndimage.interpolation import shift
> from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
> from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
> import numpy as np
>
>
> # Fetching MNIST Dataset
> mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784', version=1)
>
> # Get the data and target
> X, y = mnist["data"], mnist["target"]
>
> # Split the train and test set
> X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = X[:60000], X[60000:], y[:60000], y[60000:]
>
> # Method to shift the image by given dimension
> def shift_image(image, dx, dy):
>     image = image.reshape((28, 28))
>     shifted_image = shift(image, [dy, dx], cval=0, mode="constant")
>     return shifted_image.reshape([-1])
>
>
> # Creating Augmented Dataset
> X_train_augmented = [image for image in X_train]
> y_train_augmented = [image for image in y_train]
>
> for dx, dy in ((1,0), (-1,0), (0,1), (0,-1)):
>      for image, label in zip(X_train, y_train):
>              X_train_augmented.append(shift_image(image, dx, dy))
>              y_train_augmented.append(label)
>
>
> # Shuffle the dataset
> shuffle_idx = np.random.permutation(len(X_train_augmented))
> X_train_augmented = np.array(X_train_augmented)[shuffle_idx]
> y_train_augmented = np.array(y_train_augmented)[shuffle_idx]
>
>
> # Training on augmented dataset
> rf_clf_for_augmented = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42)
> rf_clf_for_augmented.fit(X_train_augmented, y_train_augmented)
>
> # Evaluating the model
> y_pred_after_augmented = rf_clf_for_augmented.predict(X_test)
> score = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred_after_augmented)
> print("Accuracy score after training on augmented dataset", score)
> ```

when I run this code I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'reshape'
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

```
def shift_image(image, dx, dy):
  image = image.reshape((28, 28))
```

Why does this happen? What's the problem, and how can it be resolved?

Comment: Okay, and what is your *question* about this error message? Did you *read* the error message? Did you *understand* it?

Comment: its ambiguous.  line 18/19 in the code URL above

Comment: I don't understand. What do you find ambiguous about it? It says ` 'str' object has no attribute 'reshape'`. Is there more than one `'str' object` you think it could be talking about? More than one `attribute 'reshape'`? More than one way to `have no` such attribute?

Comment: the line is ambigous.  the inputs come from the MNIST dataset.  when you debug and hover it shows an image.  when this code hits it what converted it to a STR?

Answer (score 0):

Please can you add a code block where you are using it.

Also, I believe you are passing the wrong parameters while calling this function, by mistake I think you are passing a string as argument

Comment: in the code URL its line 18/19 where a call is made to resize the image

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for dx, dy in ((1,0), (-1,0), (0,1), (0,-1)):
    for image, label in zip(X_train.values, y_train):
        X_train_augmented.append(shift_image(image, dx, dy))
        y_train_augmented.append(label)
```

Instead of:

```
for dx, dy in ((1,0), (-1,0), (0,1), (0,-1)):
    for image, label in zip(X_train, y_train):
        X_train_augmented.append(shift_image(image, dx, dy))
        y_train_augmented.append(label)
```